# Xamarin C# iOS Google tag manager not able to collect "rdid" value

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, google-tag-manager

I'm new to Xamarin Studio(C#) as well as to Google Tag Tanager(GTM), I'm facing an issue while sending hits to GTM.

I added GTM package using NuGet gallery, I have a GTM container to which I'm trying to hit some triggers of type AdWords Conversion tracking. The issue is our iOS app is not able to get/fetch the "rdid" value, whereas the Android app is perfectly fetching this value and the hits are sending successfully.

**iOS app GTM URL:** 
https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/960752408/?rdid=&label=TwzHCPfq42QQxIqQygM&ai=&remarketing_only=0&timestamp=1472524805&gclid=&appversion=2.11.0&sdkversion=gtm-i-v3.0&bundleid=ourBundleName&value=0.00&lat=1&idtype=idfa&conv=34562933&osversion=9.3.4

**Android app GTM URL:** https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/960752408/?remarketing_only=0&gclid=&idtype=advertisingid&appversion=2016110101&rdid=aaf018c7-6019-446d-9db7-5bc82b429706&label=teUxCJ_dpWMQxIqQygM&osversion=4.4.2&timestamp=1472527002&ai=&bundleid=AndroidBundleName&sdkversion=gtm-a-v3.0&value=0.00&conv=34562933&lat=0

When I tried to fix this issue, many blogs are suggesting to include the AdSupport framework forcibly but didn't find a proper way to include the framework forcibly.

Any ideas to fix this issue?